# Read TomTom (OpenLR) data in R

Tags: r, tomtom

I am looking at the way to read TomTom data in R. I know these data are in OpenLR format that, from what I have understood it is a kind of binary format. 
Does anybody know by chance if there is a way to "decode" these binary data in R without intermediate use of software from OpenLR?

Any help is very wellcome!
Thanks in advance